# Exporting non-exportable private keys in Mac

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, macos, export

How would one extract a non-exportable private key in Mac OS X 10.12.4?

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of tools for this, I'll leave this here: https://github.com/n0fate/chainbreaker  but Elcomsoft and other folks sell pretty versions ostensibly for law enforcement purposes.

The non-exportable flag for most keychains is typically a simple UI limitation not an actual security feature.  Which means it needs to be stored/extracted into memory at some point.  This is one behavior we can take advantage of.

It's a known limitation of most implementations of keychains/certstores etc. This is changing as operating systems begin to take advantage of TPMs for hardware backing of keychains.  (For example, you cannot do this on ChromeOS: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/tpm-usage)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, slightly off topic, which tool do you recommend to extract the memory image (and format)?

Comment: https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility has recently updated with symbols to support 10.12.4  you'll need to get the latest but it should work.

Comment: Thank you, there are several options in this framework. Could you please let me know the commands that I'd need to run to acquire the memory dump for volafox?